# data encapsulation using closures

Tags: clojure

I wish to know what is the idiomatic way to achieve data encapsulation
in Clojure. Below I describe my particular use case to motivate the example
code I provide.

I have code in a **dbaccess module** that performs a complex
database query to fetch some
data from a database. I also have a number of functions that operate
on the returned, raw, data. These functions then provide more
processed, refined views of the data and are invoked numerous
times with different arguments from
other modules in the system. Let's call them "*API functions*".

The query is heavy and should execute only once at the beginning,
the *API functions* will then operate on the raw-data 
from memory without having to perform another DB query.

Here's my approach using closures:

### dbaccess module

```clj
(ns dbaccess)
    (let
        [raw-data (complex-database-query)]
      (defn create-client-names []
        (fn [some-args] raw-data))
      (defn create-client-portfolio []
        (fn [some-args] raw-data))
      (defn create-client-stocks []
        (fn [some-args] raw-data)))
```

### some other client module

```clj
(def client-names (create-client-names))

(doall (map println (client-names "Baltimore")))
```

I dislike having to name the created functions that have
captured the raw-data.

More importantly, the code above doesn't allow
the client modules to configure aspects of the query before it executes
(e.g. the database connection information).

If, on the other hand, closures are not used I will have to
explicitly pass the raw-data
back and forth between the **dbaccess module** and the other modules that need to invoke *API functions*.
Is there a better way? Should I perhaps use mutable state in the **dbaccess module**?

Comment: Putting the costly query action in a run once abstraction could free you from feeling like you have to protect yourself from it. You could memoize on the query string or put the query action in a delay or future.

Comment: I don't think a let wrapped around a set of defns is idiomatic.  A memoized query sounds fine as long as it's ok for the JVM to keep that data around forever, i.e. there are a small number of possible queries, the raw data size is manageable, and/or the same query will always return the same results.  Or maybe use core.memoize so the raw data eventually goes away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I will have to explicitly pass the raw-data back and forth between the
>   dbaccess module and the other modules that need to invoke API
>   functions

You should do this, pass the data the function need explicitly, because:

- This will lead to loose coupling between how the data is created and how it is processed.
- Functions will be more clear to understand while reading it.
- Testing of the individual function will be easy as you can mock data easily.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you don't need `let` in this case:

```clj
(def ^:private raw-data (promise))

(future (deliver raw-date (complex-database-query))) ;; A. Webb mentioned this

(defn create-client-names []
  (fn [some-args] @raw-data))

...
```

Why aren't `create-client-names` and other functions just

```clj
(defn create-client-names [some-args]
  @raw-data)

...
```

?

And IMO It's better to use `doseq` instead of `map` if there is imperative body:

```clj
(doseq [name (client-names "Baltimore")]
  (println name))
```